# EventHandler doesn't fire after Thread re-creation

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

From the UI thread, i create another thread using a backgroundworker. In this thread 
i'm using the NetworkChanged eventhandler. Once the connection is lost, i DoWorkEventArgs e.Cancel, closing the thread. 
Once the network reconnects, i restart the thread using the same backgroundworker.
However, from this point the eventhandler will not fire for anymore disconnects or reconnects of the network.

The code for the eventhandler is in the Test class that is started using the initial backgroundworker.

```
    public Test()
    {
        NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged +=
            new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
    }

    protected virtual void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.IsAvailable)
            {
               IsConnectionActive = true;
               //recreate thread
            }
            else
            {
               IsConnectionActive = false;
               //Close thread
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I've read that some event's are not threadsafe, but i don't understand from other examples what i need to change to make it so. (if that even is the issue)
What is the error i've made, and also how do i get around this problem?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

Do work Code:

```
 private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender,
        DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        RunModels(worker, e);       
    }
```

Code to cancel the DoWork:

```
    public void ModelsConnectionChanged(bool sender)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sender == false)
            {
                m_currentworker.ReportProgress(0, "DISCONNECT");
                m_currentworker.CancelAsync();
                DoWork.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post (part of the) the `DoWork(...)`  code? When you want to cancel the backgroundworker, you have to check `CancelationPending` in your `DoWork` handler.

Comment: Added the code to the main question. I passed the eventhandler to my classes and renamed it DoWork (i know, the naming convention isn't the best).

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

have to be moved just before:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

They are at a wrong place. 
Furthermore, you cannot use `m_currentworker.CancelAsync();`in the `DoWork` handler; it has to be called from the point where you want to stop the worker. Furthermore, in your `RunModels(worker, e);` you have to check the `worker.CancellationPending` and stop when this flag is set to true.

What is actually happening is when you call `CancelAsync();` the flag `CancellationPending` is set to true. It is your job to return from the `DoWork(...)` as soon as possible.

Comment: Added your suggested changes, but it doesn't change the problem. Thread is cancelled. However when it restarts, the eventhandler still doesn't fire.

Comment: At least no threads are mixing up any more. Could you add some Debug.WriteLine's and see what is happening under the hoods?